# How to play a video from video url when onclick imagebutton in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-video-player

I have a image button and video url. I want that video play when user onClick image button.I want that video played on same activity if that video stream is over then I have to return to same activity.

VideoView videoView;
    ImageView btnWatchVideo;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotions_feed);

    btnWatchVideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnWatchVideo);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.ltVideoUrl);

    String path1 = "https://d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net/videos/0/_20160316_ios-user.m4v";
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path1);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    btnWatchVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoView.start();
        }

    });
```

This code is not working. Can any one suggest me how to do that.

Comment: Try ExoPlayer, It is quite smart and powerful for playing video and audio

http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these two onCreate methods for the two Activities.

**Video Vewing Activity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.ltVideoUrl);
        String path1 = "https://d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net/videos/0/_20160316_ios-user.m4v";
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path1);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 videoView.start();
             }
         });}
```

**Main Activity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnWatchVideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnWatchVideo);
        btnWatchVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class));
            }
        });}
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.example.arunmannuru.arun, PID: 30131
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arunmannuru.arun/com.example.arunmannuru.arun.PromotionsFeedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.widget.MediaController$MediaPlayerControl.isPlaying()' on a null object reference

Comment: I am getting this error when I am trying this code.

Comment: The videoView object is probably null when it is passed into mc.setMediaPlayer. Is there a VideoView tag in activity_main.xml and is that tag's id 'ltVideoUrl' ?

Comment: its not there in activity_main.xml.. I have created another activity like if the user clicks that Image button it will redirects to that activity_main2.xml having VideoView tag. Once the video is over then he can come back to the activity_main.xml. @albert braun

Comment: (android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-27 23:53:19.678 6630-6666/com.example.arunmannuru.arun I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-27 23:53:19.681 6630-6666/com.example.arunmannuru.arun W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
application was crashing

Comment: Its working actually I didn't registered that activity on the Manifest file.thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear that you made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the MediaPlayer tutorials on developer.android.com:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: I am using same tutorial as reference. Here problem is we have to create a view (video view) and that url is going to appear over there but,I am using one image button if I click that button I want that video start playing on another view. With that code it was throwing error null pointer reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this

```
 package com.mobileappdev.spotstvhdlivestreamcric.activites;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    import com.mobileappdev.spotstvhdlivestreamcric.R;
    import com.mobileappdev.spotstvhdlivestreamcric.mediaplayer.ResizeSurfaceView;
    import com.mobileappdev.spotstvhdlivestreamcric.mediaplayer.VideoControllerView;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControlListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

        private final static String TAG = MediaPlayerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private ResizeSurfaceView mVideoSurface;
        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        private VideoControllerView controller;

        private int mVideoWidth;
        private int mVideoHeight;
        private View mContentView;

        private View mLoadingView;
        private boolean mIsComplete;







        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);

            getSupportActionBar().hide();



            mVideoSurface = (ResizeSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
            mContentView = findViewById(R.id.video_container);
            mLoadingView = findViewById(R.id.loading);
            SurfaceHolder videoHolder = mVideoSurface.getHolder();
            videoHolder.addCallback(this);

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            //(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer)
            controller = new VideoControllerView.Builder(this, this)
                    .withVideoTitle("ADD VIDEO TITLE")
                    .withVideoSurfaceView(mVideoSurface)//to enable toggle display controller view
                    .canControlBrightness(true)
                    .canControlVolume(true)
                    .canSeekVideo(true)
                    .exitIcon(R.drawable.video_top_back)
                    .pauseIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_pause)
                    .playIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_play)
                    .shrinkIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_shrink)
                    .stretchIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_stretch)
                    .build((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));//layout container that hold video play view

            mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("https://d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net/videos/0/_20160316_ios-user.m4v"));
                // mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mVideoSurface.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    controller.toggleControllerView();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //        controller.show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
            mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
            mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
            if (mVideoHeight > 0 && mVideoWidth > 0)
                mVideoSurface.adjustSize(mContentView.getWidth(), mContentView.getHeight(), mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(), mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0)
                mVideoSurface.adjustSize(getDeviceWidth(this), getDeviceHeight(this), mVideoSurface.getWidth(), mVideoSurface.getHeight());
        }

        private void resetPlayer() {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        public static int getDeviceWidth(Context context) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
            return mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }

        public static int getDeviceHeight(Context context) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
            return mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        }


        // Implement SurfaceHolder.Callback
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            resetPlayer();
        }
    // End SurfaceHolder.Callback


        // Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //setup video controller view
            mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mVideoSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mIsComplete = false;
        }
    // End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

        /**
         * Implement VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
         */

        @Override
        public int getBufferPercentage() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentPosition() {
            if (null != mMediaPlayer)
                return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            else
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getDuration() {
            if (null != mMediaPlayer)
                return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
            else
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPlaying() {
            if (null != mMediaPlayer)
                return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
            else
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isComplete() {
            return mIsComplete;
        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {
            if (null != mMediaPlayer) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void seekTo(int i) {
            if (null != mMediaPlayer) {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void start() {
            if (null != mMediaPlayer) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mIsComplete = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFullScreen() {
            return getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? true : false;
        }

        @Override
        public void toggleFullScreen() {
            if (isFullScreen()) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void exit() {
            resetPlayer();
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mIsComplete = true;
        }
    }
```

Your video is playing now.